# How to stretch small wizard image over whole area in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to stretch small wizard image in Inno Setup over the whole bitmap area and hide the labels like "select installation folder"... etc. What would be the corresponding code for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Set bounds of the `WizardSmallBitmapImage` to that of its parent
- Hide the labels (`PageDescriptionLabel` and `PageNameLabel`)

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  with WizardForm.WizardSmallBitmapImage do
    SetBounds(Parent.Left, Parent.Top, Parent.Width, Parent.Height);

  WizardForm.PageDescriptionLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.PageNameLabel.Visible := False;
end;
```